# Swift NWBrowser Bonjour service error NWBrowser has no member Service

Tags: swift

I am trying to use NWBrowser to provide me list of devices on the network. I am hoping to get the port number and ip address. I am getting error and not sure what to do.

errors:

1. Type 'NWBrowser' has no member 'Service'
2. Cannot convert value of type '[Any]' to expected argument type 'NWBrowser.Descriptor'

```
import Foundation
import Network

class BonjourService {
    private let serviceType: String
    private let domain: String
    private var browseQuery: NWBrowser?
    private var services: [NWEndpoint] = []
    
    init(serviceType: String, domain: String) {
        self.serviceType = serviceType
        self.domain = domain
    }
    
    func scan(completion: @escaping ([NWEndpoint]) -> Void) {
        let parameters = NWParameters()
        let service = NWBrowser.Service(name: serviceType, type: "_\(serviceType)._tcp", domain: domain)
        
        browseQuery = NWBrowser(for: [service], using: parameters)
        
        browseQuery?.browseResultsChangedHandler = { [weak self] results, changes in
            self?.services = results.map { $0.endpoint }
            completion(self?.services ?? [])
        }
        
        browseQuery?.start(queue: .main)
    }
    
    func stopScan() {
        browseQuery?.cancel()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few incorrect assumptions here.

1. NWBrowser is specifically meant to browse for Bonjour services specified by an array of Bonjour service type strings. See Apple's [NWBrowser](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/network/nwbrowser) and [NSBonjourServices](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/nsbonjourservices). This basically means you need to know what the name of the services you are browsing for are before you browse for them. You can't browse for a generic list of devices on a network using this method.
2. The descriptor is an enum describing the type of bonjour service you want to browse for. See: [NWBrowser.Descriptor](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/network/nwbrowser/descriptor). If you aren't actively advertising a service using an NWListener then this isn't going to help you.

If you want to find a list of ip addresses of devices on your network you'll have to switch to a different network framework. Quinn on the Apple developer forums has mentioned some avenues you can approach here [IP & Port from NWBrowser](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/122638) and here [Discovering a specific device's ip](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/673771?answerId=662482022#662482022). Both posts firmly state that using NWBrowser is not the way to do this though.